# Scrolling large list in ipad safari shows blank page- Not rendering Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, html-rendering

I am developing angular 7 web app. In that application I need to display very large data to the UI. I am displaying large amount of data by appending an html string and using the innerhtml to populate the data .

I am facing probelm when I load the bid data. it takes around 15 second to load the initial data. UI becoome freeze on while loading the application. So I decided to load the data on scrolling.
But the  data is not rendered properly by showing a blank page for few seconds. I need to solve this issue on the Ipad browsers (safari and chrome)

I am using the below code.

```
  for (var index = 0; index < Lines.length; index++) {

    TemplateString += template;

       theHTML.push(template);
}
      document.getElementById('sortable').innerHTML=theHTML.join('');
```

Comment: have you tried specialized components for large data sets?

Comment: I think with a virtual scroller approach and only processing the data surrounding/nearby the area that is needed, will go a long way.  If the data needs to be sorted before displaying try to offload this processing to another device (server) and let the ipad only do the simple work